Make angular effect just execute once
I have an angular effect which I only want to be executed once.
But because it depends on other signals, I want it to wait first until all data is present.
After that first execution, I don't want it to be triggered again.
I am looking for an elegant solution (not just some boolean to flip)
With Observables you could effectively use takeUntil or take(1). But what is the signal equivalent to this?

As mentioned in the angular doc:

Effects return an EffectRef that can be used to destroy them manually,
via the .destroy() operation. This can also be combined with the
manualCleanup option to create an effect that lasts until it is
manually destroyed.

const effectRef =  effect(()=>{
    if(this.a() && this.b()){
      console.log('ReadValue');
      effectRef.destroy(); 
    }
},{manualCleanup:true});

Example
